Prettier and eslint / tslint plugins turn off randomly
I have Intellij IDEA 2023.2.3, and I usually use prettier, eslint/tslint on automatic mode, and we have .eslintrc, .prettierrc.json, and tsconfig.json files in our root directory that intellij should be pulling the config from.

Every once in a while, this setting will randomly turn off, and I will have to go back into the settings to re-enable it. I still have no idea why this happens, any ideas why this happens?

do you have your .idea files version controlled? Automaticis a default value, it can't be re-set to disable unless it's done manually

the .idea files are in our .gitignore. Is this usually included in repos?
